# Trying to figure out how to implement cookies in Gatsby.js and somehow manage them with the new GDPR law

Tags: reactjs, cookies, google-analytics, gatsby

I've tested implemented cookie hub, react-ga, gatsbu plugin-gdpr cookies.
Nothing special happends when I configure them, I can't even see any cookies inside devtools.
Has anyone come up with how to implement cookies for Gatsby and let the user choose which cookies he wants to use?
Do i need to have a special script tag inside head or should gatsby.config replace that?

kind regards, Jonathan

Unfortunately P.S has no script to display ..

Comment: Many plugins only work in "production" mode such as those google analytic ones. Did you `gatsby build` and `gatsby serve` when checking for cookies?

Comment: Wow! Did not think about that was running all the time in development mode.. Finally got the ga working thank you

Comment: Glad to help. I wrote it as an answer so you can accept it. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many plugins only work in "production" mode such as those google analytic ones. Plugins get enabled based on the `NODE_ENV` variable that Gatsby automatically sets for you everytime your program runs. With `gatsby develop` `NODE_ENV` is set to `development` which disables certain plugins.

When you `gatsby build` and `gatsby serve` this environment variable is set to `production` and thus the plugins get enabled.

**Regarding cookie consent:**

You can use projects such as [react-cookie-consent](https://github.com/Mastermindzh/react-cookie-consent):

```
import CookieConsent from "react-cookie-consent";

<CookieConsent
    enableDeclineButton
    onAccept={() => {alert("yay!")}}
    onDecline={() => {alert("nay!")}}
>
This website uses cookies to enhance the user experience.
</CookieConsent>
```

Comment: What if I want to get cookies from gatsby-node.js file?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you EliteRaceElephant! We got it to work.
But now we have stumbled upon a new obstacle.
when i try to execute Cookies.remove('_gid') etc the cookies gets deleted but appear again when changing the page. Our code looks like this ATM:

```js
import CookieConsent, { Cookies } from "react-cookie-consent";

const App = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Global.MainContainer>
        <Global.flexContainer>
          <Header />
          <div className="contentWrapper">{props.children}</div>
          <CookieConsent
            enableDeclineButton
            location="bottom"
            buttonText="Sure man!!"
            cookieName="myAwesomeCookieName2"
            style={{ background: "#2B373B" }}
            buttonStyle={{ color: "#4e503b", fontSize: "13px" }}
            onDecline={() => { Cookies.remove('_ga')
            Cookies.remove('_gat')
            Cookies.remove('_gid')}}
            setDeclineCookie={false}
          >
            This website uses cookies to enhance the user experience.{" "}
            <span style={{ fontSize: "10px" }}>
              This bit of text is smaller :O
            </span>
          </CookieConsent>
        </Global.flexContainer>
        <Footer />
      </Global.MainContainer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

We want to save the state of the user input so the cookies wont re reappear

Comment: You should write this as a new question because answers are not supposed to be more questions on this site. Feel free to link the question here. I think you stumbled upon a considerable issue regarding GDPR in Gatsby. It might be worth it to post an issue in the gatsby plugin repository on github: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-google-analytics